# Write a trigger before insert and before update

Tags: trigger

We need to keep Accounts aligned with the territory to which they belong.  Territories are defined as a set of Zip Codes,

### Account

Field                       TypeName
Name                        String
ZipCode                     String
Territory__c                Lookup(Territory)

### Territory (Territory__c)

Field Name                 Type
Name                       String
Description                String

### Territory Zip Code (Territory_Zip_Code__c)

Field Name              Type
Name                   String
ZipCode                String - External Id
Territory__c           Lookup(Territory)

Our goal is to allow Salesforce to keep Accounts always in the correct Territory__c, according to their zip code.  If no territory is defined for the zip code, the Account should not belong to any territory.

enable a system that always keeps Accounts aligned with their correct Territory__c based on the Account's zip code.  You may do anything that is available to you in Salesforce, including, but not limited to, point-and-click configuration or coding.

Comment: Neelima, Welcome to SFSE. I'm sorry. But it looks like an assignment. Perhaps you can show us what you have tried and we will help to sort out any issues you are having.

Comment: Hi, this is not an assignment , yes some one asked me in an interview so wanted to know the solution so that in my other interview it will help me ..if you know please explain

Comment: Neelima -- SFSE etiquette is to not exhort the community with 'ASAP' or 'early as possible' -- if you have a well-formed question, the community responds quite quickly and needs no encouragement

Comment: Hi Neelima, welcome to the Salesforce Stackexchange community. Before anyone answers questions on this site they want to make sure you have tried to solve the problem and that the problem is clearly defined. Please update your question with what you have already tried and include the code. If that info isn't included, people may overlook your question or vote your question down which will limit what you can do on this site. Hopefully this information helps. I wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Okay. This would not be an exact solution but I am guessing that here you have three objects.

Account and Territory Zip code which are both have lookup to Territory object.

Assumption : There is a field on account, standard or custom that stores the zip code and this scenario is not about standard territory management.

You should write a trigger on before insert and update event on **account**  object.

Assuming you inserted 10 records at a time.

Create a set of string, In that, you can put all the zip codes by iterating on **trigger.new**.

Using this set, query on territory zip code object.

```
Select zip_code__c, territory__c from territory_zip_code__c where zip_code__x in: your set
```

Then create a map in which you put zip code as key and territory__c as values.

Now again iterate over  trigger.New and get the territory to tag from the map.

Comment: I'm on my cell phone. I'll post a sudo code tomorrow morning.